# Replacing a color C#

Tags: c#, colors

I'm working on a program to generate a bitmap, which first generates a river in a blue color( Color.Blue). Now to test if the program can actually check for the same colors, so that I can replace it, I created a function that replaces the Color.Blue with Color.Yellow. The problem is that when I generate the Bitmap with the river, and then try to replace it with the other color, it can't seem to recognize the blue color, and for that matter replace it either. This is a really weird bug, and I can't seem to figure exactly what goes wrong. And I'm pretty sure it generates the river in the correct color.
Here is my color replacement code:
The "river" variable is equal to Color.Blue.

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++) {
                Color tempCol = city.GetPixel(x, y);
                if (tempCol == river) {
                    city.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Yellow);
                }
            }
        }
        pictureBox1.Image = city;
        MessageBox.Show("Done");
    }
```

Comment: Hit breakpoint on this line `if (tempCol == river)`. What is value of tempCol.G, tempCol.B, tempCol.R, tempCol.A?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in how you compare the colors. If you look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e03x8ct2.aspx), it says:

> This structure only does comparisons with other Color structures. To
>   compare colors based solely on their ARGB values, you should use the
>   ToArgb method. This is because the Equals and Equality members
>   determine equivalency using more than just the ARGB value of the
>   colors.
>
> For example, **Black** and **FromArgb(0,0,0)** are not considered
>   equal, since Black is a named color and FromArgb(0,0,0) is not.

A better comparison is thus:

```
if (tempCol.ToArgb() == river.ToArgb()) 
{
     city.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Yellow);
}
```